# Plugin development for Openfire in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, openfire

how do I best set up my environment in Intellij Idea in order to develop a plugin for Openfire? Where should I put the files required for the plugin? I have never written a plugin for anything before, if this is common knowledge, please be patient with me :)

Thanks for any replies in advance,
Yorrd

Answer (score 0):

The proper way seems to be the creation of a module with the Openfire code to be gotten on the Openfire website's download section.

The plugin itself will go into another module. The package may be called like the Openfire packages if made in order to share with the world.

The answer I got on the Jivesoftware forums can be found here: https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/52675